Conditional Formatting of multiple columns with kableExtra
I want to typeset NA values in my table in italic using kableExtra. It is easy enough to do so with one column:
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

## Randomly assign NAs
d <- mtcars[1:5, ]
rownames(d) <- NULL
set.seed(20240807)
idx <- cbind(sample(5, 12, TRUE), sample(11, 12, TRUE))
idx <- idx[!duplicated(idx), ]
d[idx] <- NA

kbl(d) %>%
  column_spec(1, italic = is.na(d[, 1]))

If I want to do the same thing for all columns, I need either to be very verbose, or to fall back to Reduce (or any other form of looping) :
kbl(d) %>%
  column_spec(1, italic = is.na(d[, 1])) %>%
  column_spec(2, italic = is.na(d[, 2])) %>%
  column_spec(3, italic = is.na(d[, 3])) %>%
  column_spec(4, italic = is.na(d[, 4])) %>%
  column_spec(5, italic = is.na(d[, 5])) # [...]

## or

kbl(d) %>%
  {
    Reduce(\(tbl, idx) 
              column_spec(tbl, idx, italic = is.na(d[, idx])), 
           1:11, .)
  }

So I was wondering whether that are basically my only options (looping or being verbose), or if there is a kableExtra canonical way of doing this?

column_spec accepts a vector of column indices.

I know, how would you specify italic = ... then?

As far as I understood, you have to provide a vector of length nrow(data) which is then applied to selected column But it must be the same for all selected columns.

OK.  I understand.  Different cells in different rows need formatting.  I think looping is your best option.  This works for me
tbl <- kbl(d)
for (i in 1:ncol(d)) {
  tbl <- tbl %>% column_spec(i, italic = is.na(d[, i]))
}
tbl

Giving


Sure, a loop does the trick (so does my Reduce approach). Yet I was wondering whether kableExtra allows for doing that also w/o a loop. The old solution using cell_spec would push that problem to the data, but as column_spec seems now to be the recommended way I thought we could use somehow reference the column number in italic= for instance.
